# iOS first steps - getting the annoying SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm watching Paul Hegarty's iOS lessons on iTunes U.
I'm developing the first app of the course.

I am randomly getting the same error (`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`), about once every two runs.
I placed breakpoints everywhere but the error seems to happen before anything gets called. I checked and re-checked my storyboard since it already happened to me that it was a problem with referenced outlets and that stuff, but everything seems fine. Also, it's so strange that it happens randomly and not programmatically.

I'm on Xcode 4.

I did a `bt` in `lldb`, but I keep getting this (same) cryptic error message (given that Matchismo is the name of the app):

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x94b49a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x94b49a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x93ba5b2f libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
    frame #2: 0x04a7f57b libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 140
    frame #3: 0x01bf3b4e GraphicsServices`GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort + 348
    frame #4: 0x01bf369f GraphicsServices`_GSEventInitialize + 123
    frame #5: 0x01bf3c1f GraphicsServices`GSEventInitialize + 36
    frame #6: 0x0001bd99 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 600
    frame #7: 0x00002a0d Matchismo`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3ac) + 141 at main.m:16
    frame #8: 0x00002935 Matchismo`start + 53
```

I don't even know if it's a meaningful question and if it can be actually answered. If not, I'm sorry. If it's necessary, I can paste the entire app code here, it's quite short actually.

### Edit

I thought that pushing to a repo and linking the repo here could really make things easier for everyone :).

https://github.com/whatyouhide/Matchismo

I think the problem is situated inside `CardGameViewController`/`CardMatchingGame`. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: @evan.stoddard I linked a GitHub repo, you can have a look at the code there.

Comment: Are you using OS X 10.8.4? If so, there is a bug in that update that affects the simulator. Use Edit Scheme and switch the debugger from LLDB to GDB.

Comment: @EvanMulawski and that it was. You saved my day and my sanity :) thank you, I'm gonna close this.

Comment: @EvanMulawski... unbelievable!  Thanks for posting this; I have spent over 6 hours trying to find the problem... you solved it for me too!

Comment: I found only LLDB, how to get to GDB ? plz help me

Comment: @RajuSidda GDB has been deprecated, and is no longer available in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error while doing Matchismo. After spending so much time, I found how to fix it. The way I fixed my error was by going in story board. Below the iPhone screen, there will be small yellow button. Right click on it and you will see that is causing error. Delete(x) it if there is yellow error sign.

If this does not fix your error then try to make new project and then replace its blank files with old files of your old project. I had same error in very beginning and by doing this program run without any error.

Other people suggests by restarting your laptop and running it again, reseting the iOS simulator, or changing iOS debugger (however this does not work in latest x code since there is only one debugger)

Hope this helps